# Multi-camera calibration for tracking objects with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, kalman-filter

I have some questions for more experienced OpenCV users concerning making a multi-camera tracking program. So to quickly present a problem I want to track multiple objects with multiple cameras. The result I want to achieve is more or less something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Dy9co0mWY0

Eventually I came to the conclusion that I want to use Kalman filter for tracking. The issues I want to ask about are:

1. Is there a way to calibrate multiple cameras based on dataset of videos like those in video link? Can it be done somehow automatically? I know you can calibrate a camera using a chessboard (http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d43/tutorial_camera_calibration_square_chess.html) but that's not the case as you don't have it in the video. There's also something like this: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d1c/tutorial_multi_camera_main.html but I guess it has the very same disadvantage.
2. What would be the most efficient way to approach tracking? Should I use Kalman filter for each view and try to merge individual result or somehow try to reconstruct the objects in 3d and then apply filter?

Any suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on automatic referee system used in volleyball matches (something like hawkeye system in tennis), and i have ball tracking implemented inside. So I can give you some suggestions:

1. Try to calibrate camera intrinsic parameters with opencv
2. Use characteristic points in your scene in order to determine camera pose (solvePnP could be good for the begining)
3. Detect object on each camera and **don't apply any filtration, approximation and interpolation** - it will decrease accuracy of your measurements
4. Reconstuct 3D coordinates of each point (using both cameras intrinsic calibrations and poses calculated)
5. Apply filtering on your result.

If you want ot achieve good, metrological results with this tracking, it could be really difficult. But it won't be for simple visualization shown on video you posted.